# Wordpress Ajax null response or parse error

Tags: ajax, wordpress, null

I'm trying to create a simple form using ajax

I'm following in the information here: http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#admin-ajax

If I use this code

```
    function myajax_submit() {
        // get the submitted parameters

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        // generate the response
        $response = json_encode( array( 'success' =&gt; true ) );

        // response output
        header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
        echo $response;

        // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
        exit;
    }
```

I get a parse error

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /Users/worker/Desktop/MAMP-DocRoot/the_site/src/php/wp-content/themes/hub/functions.php on line 49
```

line 59 is

```
    $response = json_encode( array( 'success' =&gt; true ) );
```

If I comment out this line I get a 500 Internal Server Error in the console.

```
    http://sitename.co.uk/hub/wp-content/plugins/Users/worker/php/wp-content/themes/hub//js/compiled/main.min.js?ver=3.9.1
```

The form works but I get an alert of null

If I check in the Network tab and click on admin-ajax.php it has a Status Code of 200 OK

Comment: &gt; is equivalent to > sign, remove it and and 'true' too, your line 59 become `$response = json_encode( array( 'success') );`

Comment: Thank you Jerome that stopped the null response. I'm still getting the 500 Interal Server Error - any ideas

Comment: If you are getting 500 internal server error, there is another error with the script or something else on the server side. Find the actual error message, then we might be able to help!

Comment: Where would I find an error message. In the console I get  http://sitename.co.uk/hub/wp-content/plugins/Users/worker/php/wp-content/themes/hub//js/compiled/main.min.js?ver=3.9.1 with a status of 500 Internal Server Error